# Trying to add try and catch to code, stuck

Tags: java, try-catch

I need to implement a try and catch around 2 blocks of code. each need there own. code that I have written. I have made a class for it:

```
public boolean makeOffer(int offer) throws OfferException
{
  // reject offer if sale is not open for offers
  if (this.acceptingOffers == false)
  {
     return false;
  }

  // reject offer if it is not higher than the current highest offer
  else if (offer <= this.currentOffer)
  {
     throw new OfferException("Offer not High enough!");
  }

  else
  {
     // new offer is valid so update current highest offer
     this.currentOffer = offer;

     // check to see if reserve price has been reached or exceeded
     if (this.currentOffer >= this.reservePrice)
     {
        // close the Sale if reserve has been met
        this.acceptingOffers = false;
     }

     return true;
  }
}
```

second blockis very similar to the first as this is in a separate class to the first.

```
public boolean makeOffer(int offer)
{
  // reject offer if sale is not open for offers
  if (this.acceptingOffers == false)
  {
     return false;
  }

  // reject offer if it is not higher than the current highest offer
  else if (offer <= this.currentOffer)
  {
     return false;
  }

  else
  {
     // new offer is valid so update current highest offer
     this.currentOffer = offer;

     // check to see if reserve price has been reached or exceeded
     if (this.currentOffer >= this.reservePrice)
     {

        System.out.println("Name of the Highest Bidder: ");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.highestBidder = s.nextLine();

        s.close();
        this.acceptingOffers = false;
     }
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: Are you referring to message variable later? if not remove that and just use super(message) inside the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a method that throws an `Exception` you have to use the keywords `throws` (unless you throw a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true). These do not have to be declared this way). In this way, the other methods that call this method can handle the exception.

You can use something like this:

```
private static void submitOffer() throws OfferException{

 // ...
 if ( sales[i].getSaleID().equalsIgnoreCase(saleID)){   

    //try {  Remove this try
    offerAccepted = sales[i].makeOffer(offerPrice);
    if (offerAccepted == true){
       System.out.print("Offer was accepted"); 
       if(offerPrice <= sales[i].getReservePrice()){
             System.out.print("Reserve Price was met");
       }else{
          throw new OfferException("Resever not met!");
       }
    }else{
       throw new OfferException("Offer was Not accepted");
    }

    //....

}
```

}

When you call the `submitOffer()` method you can use:

```
public void myMethod() throws OfferException{
  MyClass.submitOffer();
}
```

or

```
public void myMethod(){
  try{
    MyClass.submitOffer();
  } catch( OfferException oe){
     //handle here the exception
  }
}
```

Also if you are using a custom `Exception` you should call the super constructor.

```
public class OfferException extends Exception{

   String message;

   public OfferException(String message){
        super(message); //call the super constructor
        this.message = message;   //Do you need it ?
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use super(message) as well inside the custom exception

Comment: im ment to use try. So im abit confused. it works but i need to put a catch in

Comment: @AaronRoss you need to put a catch if you are calling a method that throws an Exception.

Comment: thanks, that fixed it. i edited to a different section i have the same problem with @GabrieleMariotti